# Iterate the dependency graph in CMake to generate list of link library files used for CGO

Tags: c++, go, cmake, cgo

I want to iterate over all link libraries of a target `target` to build a list of all library binaries (static libraries) which `target` links to, e.g.

```
add_executable(exe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe fmt::fmt otherExe)
```

We want a list of all library binary files (by using [`$<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:tgt>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_LINKER_FILE)) for dependent targets `fmt::fmt` and `otherExe` to generate the apropriate CGO `interface.go` file with `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

The thing is, it's hard to write a loop in CMake to iterate over link dependencies of `target` since
properties like `LINK_LIBRBARIES` and `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` are in general lists but might contain generator expressions, as in the case for interface library target `fmt::fmt` which comes from Conan where `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` resolves to
`$<$<CONFIG:Release>:CONAN_LIB::fmt_fmt_RELEASE;>`. which **contains** a semicolon ";" which is then treated itself as a list with `$<$<CONFIG:Release>:CONAN_LIB::fmt_fmt_RELEASE;` and `>`.

This is due to that Conan adds the following

```
set_property(TARGET fmt::fmt
             PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES
             $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${fmt_LIBRARIES_TARGETS_RELEASE}
                                           ${fmt_OBJECTS_RELEASE}> APPEND)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The only reliable way for obtain list of linked libraries is [file(GENERATE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#generate) command which expands generator expressions. Because of expanding generator expressions, the command generates a file only at the **end of configuration process**. Every other way of obtaining list of linked libraries will be limited in its usage.

Comment: Thats true and a good point, however even with `file(GENERATE` its hard if not impossible to get to *generate* a list of resolved `$TARGET_LINKER_FILE:tgt` since you cannot apply that to `$<$<CONFIG:Release>:CONAN_LIB::fmt_fmt_RELEASE;>` (semicolon and possible multiple values), another solution would be the [file api](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html) but dunno yet how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution by using the [file-api](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html) of Cmake, we setup a "configure"  `add_custom_target` in CMake which is a pyhton script which is reading the reply for the 'codemodel-v2' (file-api): parsing the JSON output file for the target of interest. Then
gathering all linker and compiler flags from this JSON and then configure a Go file with these flags.

Include files have been extracted by passing [`$<TARGET_PROPERTY:targetName,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_PROPERTY) to the `add_custom_command`.